# SetCursorPosition equivalent in java console

Tags: java, console

I want to move cursor up to the beginning after it wrote something at lower part.  I mean is there something like SetCursorPosition(0,0)?

edit:  it is about writing 6x3 matrix with numbers in it. it should be seem like this

```
     ...
     7 8 9
     4 5 6
     1 2 3
```

it'll start write from bottom. when the cursor at (0,0) it'll put 6x space then write 1 2 3, then go to (0,0), put 5x space, write 4 5 6 ...

code:

```
boolean sa;        
    int yoyo;
    int lo = 18;
    int y = 0;

    for (int k = 1; k < 100; k++)
    {

        if (y < 18)
        {
            sa = true;
            for (int h = 2; h < k; h++)
            {
                if (k % h == 0)
                    sa = false;
            }
            if (sa)
            {
                lo--;

                if (y % 3 == 0)
                {
                    yoyo = lo / 3 + 1;
                    // here where I need Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0)

                    for (int yos = 0; yos < yoyo; yos++)
                    {
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }
                    if (k < 10)
                        System.out.print(" " + k + " ");
                    else
                        System.out.print(k + " ");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (k< 10)
                        System.out.print(" " + k + " ");
                    else
                        System.out.print(k + " ");
                }


                y++;

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is the code where you want to do *something like SetCursorPosition(0,0)*?!

Comment: @R.J editted the question. Can you recheck it

Comment: You've edited and just added more about the question(which is good), but then, where is the code you've written till now?!

Comment: @R.J I didnt write the project yet it was just thought. I ll write in 5 sec.

Comment: @R.J can you check again please

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't have full console support.

You might try [JLine](https://jline.github.io).

Answer (score 0):

I asked the developers of [JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline3) and you can set the cursor position using this.

```
terminal.puts(InfoCmp.Capability.cursor_address, 0, 0);
```

Here's a small example of it's usage and as an added bonus I'll show how to make the cursor invisible and visible.

```
import org.jline.terminal.Terminal;
import org.jline.terminal.TerminalBuilder;
import org.jline.utils.InfoCmp;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CursorStuff
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int row = 10;
        int col = 40;
        Terminal terminal = TerminalBuilder.terminal();
        terminal.puts(InfoCmp.Capability.cursor_address, row, col);
        System.out.println("Here we start at row " + row + " col " + col);
        System.out.println("Now you see the cursor");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        terminal.puts(InfoCmp.Capability.cursor_invisible);
        System.out.println("Now you don't!");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        terminal.puts(InfoCmp.Capability.cursor_visible);
        System.out.println("And the cursor is back again.");

    }
}
```

Make sure to have either [Jansi](http://fusesource.github.io/jansi/download.html) or [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) in your libraries otherwise you will get a dumb terminal and not be able to use these functions at least on Windows as it requires these to do native function calls.

As far as I can tell this is the easiest method to accomplish this as before I knew this was an option I was writing C++ and calling those native function calls I made using JNI.